# .NET Core: Correct way of using async/await modifier in C# console application

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, console-application

I am wondering if the following methods in the `Main` method implement `async/await` modifier correctly as to imposing the asynchronous programming in my `C#` `.NET Core` console application.

**Main method:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  //...

  MyTask_1_RunAsync(dbConnectionString).Wait();
  MyTask_2_RunAsync(dbConnectionString).Wait();  

  //...
}
```

**Other methods:**

```
static async Task MyTask_1_RunAsync(string dbConnectionString)
{
   //....

   var content = new StringContent(paramObj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content);
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

   //...
}

static async Task MyTask_2_RunAsync(string dbConnectionString)
{
   //....

   var content = new StringContent(paramObj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content);
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

   //...
}
```

Comment: Use `async Task Main()` instead of calling `.Wait()` on every async method.

Comment: It depends on what you expect to have happen. This code isn't obviously wrong, but may not do what you intend it to do.

Comment: `async Task Main` was introduced in C# 7.1 but even with older versions it's a lot better to put all the code into a separate `async` method that's called with `TheAsyncMain().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. At the very least, you'll get the actual exception in case of problems instead of an `AggregageException` wrapping the actual exception.